# Adding DateTime.Now; to a URL for a test in Selenium-Webdriver and C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I am trying to navigate to a specific URL as the Given statement for an automated test case and use a DateTime.Now structure to insert a required date into the URL for the browser to navigate to, unfortunately there is currently no way around navigating this way for this specific scenario.

My gherkin is:

```
 Scenario Outline: Search
    Given I Navigate to webpage with <date>

    Examples:
        | Variant | Date |
        | Web1    |      |
        | Web2    |      |
        | Web3    |      |
        | Web4    |      |
        | Web5    |      |
```

My regex for the Given statement is as follows:

```
 [Binding]
    public class Search
    {
        [Given(@"I Navigate to WebPage with (.*)")]
        public void GivenINavigateToWebpageWith(int date)
        {
            DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
            String[] formats = { "yyyyMMdd" };
            String[] cultureNames = { "en-US" };
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            CurrentBrowserNavigation("https://webpage.com/foo/bar/blah/blah/en-us/?startdate=" + date + "&anotherThing=1");
        }
```

I know this isn't correct and doesn't work currently but I'm a little lost as to how to properly construct this and was hoping to get pointed in the right direction by the community here. Hope this has enough detail!

Comment: Let me clear the picture a little bit right here. So you are trying to navigate to the URL something like this: webpage.com/foo/bar/blah/blah/en-us/?startdate=20171120&anotherThing=1        ??

Comment: @GordonFreaman essentially yes. the startdate should ideally be formatted as 2017-11-20 but I'm not quite sure if C# accepts that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will help as you mentioned that date format to expect is 2017-11-20:

```
            [Binding]
            public class Search
            {
                [Given(@"I Navigate to WebPage with (.*)")]
                public void GivenINavigateToWebpageWith(int date)
                {
                    var todayDate = DateTime.Now;
                    var localtime = todayDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");                
                    CurrentBrowserNavigation("https://webpage.com/foo/bar/blah/blah/en-us/?startdate=" + localtime + "&anotherThing=1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does C# not have a library to handle query params?